# Blurry wallpapers, no matter the resolution

Tags: display, desktop-background, display-resolution

So I've simply been trying to set a new desktop wallpaper, but no matter how high the resolution of the images I use (I've even tried using images up to a resolution of 70MP) the images still appear stretched and blurry, as if they were tiny. Whenever I try to centre them they just show up tiny in the centre of the screen, and I have no idea why this could be?